# Calculate Chi-square with NA values

Tags: r, statistics, na, chi-squared

I want to perform a chi-squared test between two values with missing data. How can I do this?
I've looked this up several times and across different sources, none of which had been successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you want to perform a chi-squared test between two random variables x, y using the Pearson's Chi-squared test.

You can use the formula as it is i.e. `chisq.test(x,y)` or `chisq.test(cont_table)` where cont_table is the contingency table of random variables x and y.

As it is mentioned on the documentation of the function (link1):

"If x is a matrix with at least two rows and columns, it is taken as a two-dimensional contingency table: the entries of x must be non-negative integers. Otherwise, x and y must be vectors or factors of the same length; **cases with missing values are removed**, the objects are coerced to factors, and the contingency table is computed from these."

You cannot (and should not) perform a chi-squared test with missing values included in your vectors/matrix because it would lead to erroneous results.

check these links for more info: [link1](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/chisq.test.html) [link2](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/goodness-fit/chi-squared-test-independence)

Comment: I was using the contingency table way and for some reason the rows with NA values i had removed before were being considered. However when I tryed the first method `chisq.test(x,y)` it worked well. =D Thanks.